# how help screen show for one time only in android

Tags: android

in the following code work properly and show help screen when open activity but I want show one time forever,

what can i do?

What should I add  in the code?

my code:

```
public class KhatmMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Context ctx;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     ctx = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.khatmmain);

    showOverLay();
.
.
.

}

private void showOverLay(){

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.overlay_view);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.overlayLayout);

layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        dialog.dismiss();

    }

});

dialog.show();

 }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a one time welcome screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976406/how-to-display-a-one-time-welcome-screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SharedPrefereces` to set a variable that will check if you've shown the dialog yet to the user or not, here's an example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.you.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean dialogShown = prefs.getBoolean("dialogShown", false);
```

Then check if the value of `dialogShown` is false (you don't need to set it first since it will default to false the way we are calling it), then on the following code we execute some code, **only** if `dialogShown` is false, meaning we can do all the dialog stuff inside that conditional:

```
if(!dialogShown){
    //Your show dialog code
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("dialogShown",true).commit();
}
```

So the next time we check for the `dialogShown` value on the shared preferences it will be `true` therefor not showing the dialog. I believe this is the most common way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution ..

when application first time start then save the shared preference to the app..

Now each and every time You retrieve the shared preference and check if it is there then move to next screen

Comment: This is not relevant Example but in this example short-cut is creating onece at starting of app http://pulse7.net/android/android-application-shortcut-home-screen/

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
public class KhatmMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Context ctx;
Boolean showOneTime = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     ctx = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.khatmmain);

    showOverLay();
.
.
.

}

private void showOverLay(){
    if (showOneTime == false) {
        return;
    }
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.overlay_view);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.overlayLayout);

layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        dialog.dismiss();

    }

});

dialog.show();
showOneTime = false;
 }
 }
```