# How to determine when the app is loading in Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have been trying to find guidance on how to make a loading splash screen in Android, and have found tutorials such like [A Simple Android Splash Screen](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/a-simple-android-splash-screen/).  Because this tutorials glosses over certain things, one thing that's a bit unclear to me is how do you programmatically determine whether the app is trying to load (before the `onCreate()` method for your activity executes and your activity loads)?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your question. You want to know what makes the splash screen activity start ? Maybe you should read a bit of life cycle of android apps http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: No, I'm trying to work out what goes before onCreate().  The issue is for my app while onCreate() is executing there is a black screen for some time.  I'm trying to work out how to put in a loading splash screen while that black screen is there, it is only there when the app is first installing.  Make sense?

Comment: There is no such concept in Android. If you really want to have a spash screen (it is considered bad practice) you need to implement an activity that shows the splash screen (after it's `onCreate` has finished)

Comment: OK, well one of the other tutorials I looked at recommended having a progress bar as an AsyncTask.  Would I be better off doing that?

Comment: OK so you don't really need to know what it does before you just need to open the xml file you created for the splash screen and add elements. Rather images or progress bar in you case. If you want to be just the first time the you need to add logic.

Comment: also if you just want to see it once look  here and please search how to do what you want first so there is no repeted questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976406/how-to-display-a-one-time-welcome-screen

Comment: An AsyncTask must be started from an activity, so no real advantage. Moreover, the activity can be recreated, for example if the orientation changes. The splash screen should not be shown again in this case. Therefore I think it is better to use a dedicated splash screen activity.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [Instrumentation Class.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html)  It is used to monitor such things, and should provide you with whatever you want know.  Also, putting the Dalvik messages to Verbose in LogCat will give you an idea of everything the system is doing prior to calling your Activity's `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The `onCreate()` method of android is called when its time for it to render the UI. The condition that you are specifying by

> one thing that's a bit unclear to me is how do you programmatically
>   determine whether the app is trying to load (before the onCreate
>   method for your activity executes and your activity loads)?

would be using someting in manifest like `splashScreen="@drawable/Splash"` but this unfortunately doesnt exist

So the solution would be like this

Calling a temporary XML file before loading your actual content

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    // Do your loading code here
    // Create an AsyncTask if the task is time consuming

    //Now Load your actual UI
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

you said

> The issue is for my app while onCreate() is executing there is a black
>   screen for some time

The short black screen is for very few seconds and there is no way around for it.