# Show Google Play Games Welcome Dialog on all app launches

Tags: android, google-play-games

The best example of what I am trying to attempt can be described by the behavior of the simcity app (and I'm sure many others that I may be unaware of also using the google sign in for Google play games). Once you sign in to google play games on simcity, every time from then on that you launch the app a popup that slides from the top of the screen is displayed that says, "Welcome **user*". Now in my app I have followed all of google's documentation (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) and various other sources, and the only time I see the "welcome" popup is after the user is logged in the first time. The only code I have in `onResume` and `onStart` is `mGoogleApi.connect()` which is the exact same code I have when the sign in button is clicked the first time and the welcome dialog is shown.

My question is this: Am I missing something with how to get this dialog displayed, or are apps such as simcity somehow signing me out on every time I close the app and then back in when I open it again? (To me that doesn't seem to make sense but is presently the only logical explanation I can think of.)

To be 100% precise, the below image is exactly what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The welcome message is not shown on every call to signin or authenticate. If the user has been "recently" signed into the app, then the message is not shown.  This is a little confusing, since the connect happens silently. You can confirm you are connected by calling mGoogleAPI.isConnected() in the code.

I quoted "recently" since it is actually determined by the Play Game Services. It is designed to make it less distracting to the user, so they focus on the actual game vs. an indication that they are signed in.

Comment: This answer should be accepted - this is exactly how the banner works. You can attempt to verify this by setting your system clock forward a day or so and re-opening your app.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try using [PreferenceScreen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html) which, represents a top-level `Preference` that is the root of a Preference hierarchy. A `PreferenceActivity` points to an instance of this class to show the preferences.

Here's an example XML layout of a `PreferenceScreen`:

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:key="first_preferencescreen">
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="wifi enabled"
            android:title="WiFi" />
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="second_preferencescreen"
            android:title="WiFi settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="prefer wifi"
                android:title="Prefer WiFi" />
        ... other preferences here ...
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

For a more detailed information, you may check the complete [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). Additionally, solution given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976406/how-to-display-a-one-time-welcome-screen) might also help.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this would help me